# Grails 4 - Mail Plugin: IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate mail body .... Is it in a plugin?

Tags: grails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, grails-plugin

I have a Grails REST API that is using the Grails Mail plugin to send emails.  It works well locally, but on AWS elastic beanstalk, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate mail body /mail/denial. Is it in a plugin? If so you must pass the
 plugin name in the [plugin] variable
```

I do have a GSP called `denial.gsp` located at the path `/mail/denial.gsp`.  I exploded the WAR file and verified that it was being built into the WAR at the right path.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was actually with the GSP plugin, which is used by the Grails Mail Plugin. The answer was in the [Introduction to GSPs](https://gsp.grails.org/4.0.0/guide/index.html#introduction) in the Grails 4 Docs, where it says to add `apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"` to `build.groovy`.

[image]

Well, I'm sure I won't be the last person to not read the docs.  Hopefully, this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: It looks like you posted an answer to your own question less than a minute after you posted the question.  Is that what happened?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown , yes, I actually posted them at the exact same time using the "Answer Your Own Question" option that StackOverflow gives whenever you ask a question.  I wasn't looking for an answer. I posted them so other people with the same problem could search for the error message and find the solution.

Comment: "I posted them so other people with the same problem could search for the error message and find the solution." - I don't know if that is consistent with SO guidelines or not, but another option that would be an even bigger benefit to the community would be to add some clarity to the docs, which are open source.  Would you be willing to help author some clarifying content?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown , please see the blog post [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions), in which they state "To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."

Comment: @JeffScottBrown , Good point about updating the docs. I just submitted [pull request #53](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/mail/pull/53) to the Grails Mail Plugin with an update to the documentation.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!